# I am receiving 404 for all assets when hosting sails.js application on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, sails.js, gitlab-ci, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I want to run a sails.js application on Google Kubernetes Engine. Running the application docker container locally works perfectly.
The deployment to GKE is done via gitlab Auto-Devops pipelines. Deploying the application to GKE is working so far and I can access pages of the sails.js application using the generated domain by gitlab-CI - e.g. `xyz-review-autodevops-123.my.host.com`

But when accessing pages, only the requested page can be loaded - every asset like images, javascript and css files are not loaded but return a 404.

When looking at the nginx-ingress-controller logs in GKE, I see that these url's are requested but result in a 404:

```
[05/Aug/2018:12:27:25 +0000] "GET /js/cloud.setup.js HTTP/1.1" 404 9 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36" 573 0.004 [my-app-review-autodevops-1232u0-my-app-443] xx.xx.xx.xx:80 9 0.004 404
```

There are also regularly errors logged as the following. I am not sure if this is related to this issue but still want to mention it in case it is:

```
error obtaining PEM from secret my-app-1239989/review-autodevops-1232u0-my-app-tls: error retrieving secret my-app-1239989/review-autodevops-1232u0-my-app-tls: secret my-app-1239989/review-autodevops-1232u0-my-app-tls was not found"
```

My guess is that ingress does not know the requested host for the assets because they are requested as absolute paths (`/js/cloud.setup.js`) instead of relative paths (`js/cloud.setup.js`) and therefore does not know where to route this request to because the domain information is lost in the request.

But I do now kow how I fix this 404 issue. Would changing all paths to relative paths in sails.js fix it? I even don't know if this can easily be done since quite some are generated by grunt tasks in sails.js and are generated in the absolute form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, found the error by myself.
This was a silly mistake because sails was somehow configured to include `grunt` and `sails-hook-grunt` only as devdependencies in `package.json`.

Since on the production container, `NODE_ENV` is set as environment variable, `npm install` only installs the production dependencies.

And since grunt is used for manipulating and providing the assets in sails.js, those have just not been generated.

The solution was to move `grunt` and `sails-hook-grunt` to the `dependencies` in `package.json`.

Comment: Thank you! this really saved me